# set syntax: php on .class files

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using the sublime text 3 with php, but in the system there is some old files which have .class extension (ie: Contact.class instead of Contact.php) and so i have to set syntax: php every time a open such file.

Its possible to set so this extension is recognized as php by default ?

Comment: @watcher no, it's not. OP is asking about syntax highlighting in Sublime, not how to set up extensions on the server...

Answer (score 0):

Open a `.class` file in Sublime, then select **`View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as... -> PHP`**. Now, all files with this extension will be opened as PHP files.